# Insecure pseudo random functions

Tags: mac, pseudo-random-function, cbc-mac

Let $F$ be a pseudo-random function. Show that the following constructions are insecure as message authentication codes (in each case $K \in \{0,1\}^n$ is the private key):

$(a)$ To authenticate a message $m=m_1||m_2||\dots||m_l$ where $m_i\in \{0,1\}^n$, compute
$$
t=F_k(m_1)\oplus F_k(m_2)\oplus \dots \oplus F_k(m_l) \mbox{ as the tag}
$$

(b) To authenticate a message $m=m_1||m_2||\dots||m_l$ where $m_i\in \{0,1\}^n$, do the following:

$$
r\stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \{0,1\}^n
$$
$$
t \leftarrow F_k(r)\oplus F_k(m_1) \oplus F_k(m_2) \oplus \dots \oplus F_k(m_l) \\
send (r,t)
$$

This is what I have tried:

(a) Designing an Adversary: Query $m_i$ and get $t_i$ $\forall i= 1$ to $n$

$t=t_1 \oplus t_2 \oplus t_3 \oplus \dots \oplus t_l$

return $(m,t)$

$\Pr[\text{Adversary forges}]=1$

$(b)$ Designing an Adversary: Query $m_1||m_1$ get $t^{*}$ $(F_k(r))$

Query $m_i$ get $t_i$ $(F_k(r)\oplus F_k(m_i)) $

${t_i}^{'}=t_i \oplus t^{*}$

$t=t^*\oplus {t_1}^{'} \oplus {t_2}^{'} \oplus \dots \oplus {t_l}^{'}$

return $(m,t)$

$\Pr[\text{Adversary forges}]=1$.

Any help with the answers will be truly appreciated.

Comment: a) It is not about forging $m$ it is about forging a new message that is not seen yet! try swapping positions?

Comment: @kelalaka actually, the given attack is fully valid for a) as it forges an attack on the unseen concatenation of the individually queried parts.

Comment: @SEJPM yes, it valid, however, I felt that the OP feels to forge $m$. That is the reason that I need to give simple, maybe not enough, clarification. In their way, 2 queries were enough.

Comment: What about (b)?

Comment: Hint for b) In the second game, the $r$ is part of the signature that is protected the PRF $F$. No problem, If the blocks are different, then one can forge $\ell!-1$ different messages of size $\ell$.

Comment: The issue with the current solution for b) is that $r$ is freshly random for each of the individual $m_i$ queries preventing you from extracting $F_k(r)$ using $t^*$.

Comment: I think I am not getting part b, if anyone can answer that it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: For a) wouldn't $(m|m, 0)$ be also a valid forgery $\forall m$ ?

Comment: Hint for 2: Try querying some part of message first. Then try removing r of the first query while adding (and/or removing) blocks of message in second.